# Курсор и for update в качестве блокировки таблицы

Tags: plsql, database-cursor

Если создать в процедуре курсор

```
CURSOR cs1 IS SELECT * FROM tour_order FOR UPDATE;
```

В начале процедуры его открыть, а в конце закрыть, то будет ли происходить блокировка всех данных во время всей процедуры? Или обязательно нужно использовать fetch ?